# App info kafka.consumer for group-id unregistered

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-cloud-stream

I have seen this particular log "App info kafka.consumer for group-id unregistered" so many times in our logs in our Kafka consumer service which uses Spring Cloud Stream. I couldn't understand why we are seeing it. Our Kafka consumer seems to be working fine. Can anyone please help me understand what this log is? Do we see when the consumers are rebalancing?

I did a google search but couldn't get an answer